# C user input only integers, return value from scanf

Tags: c, return-value, user-input, scanf

I am trying to get some user input, and I want to make sure that they enter integers, and if they don't I will just ask them to type again (loop until they get it right).

I have found a lot of different approaches to do this; some more complicated then others. But I found this approach which seems to work.

But I just don't really get why this is tested in the code:

```
scanf("%d%c", &num, &term) != 2
```

I can understand that `scanf` outputs the number of items successfully matched and assigned, but I don't get why it outputs 2 if it is an integer.

The code in C is:

```
int main(void)
{
    int num;
    char term;

    if (scanf("%d%c", &num, &term) != 2 || term != '\n')
        printf("failure\n");
    else
        printf("valid integer followed by enter key\n");
}
```

Trying to put it in loop:

```
int main(void){

int m, n, dis;
char m_check, n_check, dis_check;

do{
    m = 0; n = 0; dis = 0;
    m_check = ' '; n_check = ' '; dis_check = ' ';

printf("Please enter number of rows m in the matrix (integer): ");
if(scanf("%d%c", &m, &m_check) !=2 || m_check != '\n')
        m_check = 'F';

printf("Please enter number of columns n in the matrix (integer): ");
if(scanf("%d%c", &n, &n_check) !=2 || n_check != '\n')
            n_check = 'F';

printf("Should the random numbers come from a uniform or normal distribution?... 
Please press 1 for uniform or 2 for normal: ");
if(scanf("%d%c", &dis, &dis_check) !=2 || dis_check != '\n' || dis != 1 || dis !=2)
            dis_check = 'F';

}while(m_check == 'F'  || n_check == 'F' || dis_check == 'F');
```

I've tried just inputting m = 3, n = 3, dis = 2, and then the loop just starts over and asks me to input number of rows. And if I when asked for this press f or something it just start looping like crazy over the printf-statements :)

Comment: Do you mean why `term` also can be an integer?

Comment: If both `%d` and `%c` is successful, `scanf` will return 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entering an integer will match to the formatter `%d` and will assign the value to the variable `num`. The `%c` formatter will take the newline character ('\n') and store it in the variable `term`. `scanf` returns 2 cause 2 elements where correctly assigned (`num` and `term`)

If you don't enter an integer the formatter `%d` won't match correctly, and `scanf` won't return 2, producing a failure

Edit: Your do-while loop goes crazy cause your conditions in the last scanf are wrong (`dis != 1 || dis !=2`). It should be

```
if(scanf("%d%c", &dis, &dis_check) !=2 || dis_check != '\n' || (dis != 1 && dis !=2))
```

Comment: Okay this makes sense - So if you write something like "hfkd44" then the letters will be assigned to term and then "term != '\n'", will be true ?

Comment: @Linda Term will be just 'h' (It's a single character). The term variable is to prevent you from writing something like `12abc`. In this case `num = 12` and `term  = 'a'`, cause `term != '\n'` it will fail

Comment: Also note that if you input `12.56`, will fail too (`term = '.'`)

Comment: Oooh okay cool :) I think I understand it now, but I am having quite some trouble using it in my program, where i want to use it in a loop, but it just keeps looping it, even if I write a integer. And if I write a non integer it just goes crazy and loops without letting the user input anything - if I put it in the question could you maybe help me see where I go wrong? :)

Comment: @Linda I'll try, just add your code and what did you input :)

Comment: @Linda Found it, hope this helps you :)

Comment: oooh, of course, it doesn't make any sense the other way - thank you very much, that fixed it :)

Comment: `if(scanf("%d%c", &dis, &dis_check) !=2 || dis_check != '\n' ...` fails when `scanf()` returns 1  (number followed by EOF) and then code attempts to test `dis_check != '\n'` without certainly having a valid value in `dis_check`.

Comment: But it still goes in to a crazy loop where it just prints without letting the user type anything, if you type something that isn't an integer :(

Comment: @Linda That's cause when you input a char it can't match any of your `scanf` (Yours are expecting an integer and then a char) so it goes to the next `scanf` (which can't match either) and so on. To fix it you can add `while(getchar() != '\n');` inside the last `if(scanf...`. It's important the `;`, it just keeps cleaning your buffer until it consumes the '\n' (The first one that wasn't consumed)

Comment: hmmm... I think I understand why it does it now, but I am not sure I understand the solution. Do you mean like this:                                               if(scanf(" %d%c", &dis, &dis_check) !=2 || dis_check != '\n' || (dis != 1 && dis !=2)|| while(getchar() != '\n');)
 dis_check = 'F';                       my computer says syntax error :)

Comment: No :s I mean this:

`if(scanf(" %d%c", &dis, &dis_check) !=2 || dis_check != '\n' || (dis != 1 && dis !=2)){ while(getchar() != '\n'); dis_check = 'F';}`

Comment: About the solution, cause `scanf` can't match returns 0 (No arguments succesfuly assigned) and doesn't consume the buffer (Your input). Then the buffer goes to the next `scanf` and so on. To prevent this you clean the buffer (consuming it with `getchar`) until you consume the `'\n'`. Cause once any `scanf` all subsequent `scanf`s will fail, you can do this in the last `scanf` failure so the non-matching input doesn't go to the next loop

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` returns the number of fields it converted. You have the format string `%d%c`; it has:

1. `%d` - first field
2. `%c` - second field

so `scanf` returns 2.

If the user enters a number e.g. `123` and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, your `num` will be equal to `123`, and `term` will be `\n`.

If the user enters a number with garbage at the end, e.g. `123garbage` and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, your `num` will be equal to `123`, the `term` will be `g`, and `arbage\n` will remain in the input buffer.

In both cases, `scanf` read an `int` and a `char`, so it returns 2.

A different example: the user enters `garbage123`. In this case, `scanf` will fail to read an integer, and return 0.

So your code checks for two different forms of incorrect output.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d%c", &num, &term) != 2
```

This checks the `return` value of `scanf` . It will `return` number of arguments correctly matched . So , if a `integer` and a character is entered , they are store in vairables `num` and `term`  and `scanf` `returns` `2` .

`scanf` will not `return` `2` if both the arguments are not correctly matched , in that case `failure` will be displayed as output.

Comment: `12.3` as input will not fail this test and OP wants "make sure that they enter integers".

Answer (score 0):

Oops - now see OP wants to know why approached failed and was not necessarily looking for a how-to do it.  Leaving this up as a reference as it does assert the fundamental problem: `scanf()`.  Do not use it for *user* input.

---

If code truly needs to "get some user input, and wants to make sure that they enter integers", then use `fgets()` to get the line and *then* process the input.

Mixing user input with scanning/parse invariably results in some user input defeating the check, extra user input in `stdin` or improperly waiting for more input.

```
// true implies success
bool Read_int(int *value) {
  char buffer[100];
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) return false; // EOF or error

  // Now parse the input
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long number = strtol(buffer, &endptr, 10);
  if (errno)                                return false; // long overflow
  if (number < INT_MIN || number > INT_MAX) return false; // int overflow
  if (endptr == buffer)                     return false; // No conversion
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr)) endptr++;
  if (*endptr)                              return false; // non-white-space after number
  *value = (int) number;
  return true;
}
```